# Sending info and other questions for windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, themes, android-mapview

I'm rather noob for WP7 developing, and I've got some questions for my new app:

1. Is it possible to send some information from time to time to my server while the app is hidden (running at background) ? If it is possible, won't it be rejected by Microsoft (my app will say to user about this, of course) ? I want to watch user's location and send it to server, to be honest:)
2. Is it possible to draw overlays for MapViews? I know, that for iOS apps it is possible
3. Is it a bad practice for Silverlight apps to put my own images under all buttons and controls on page, and to redefine controls' style? I don't want to support native themes

Thanks!

Comment: you should make one question for each of your questions...

Comment: With 1 you'll need a privacy notice and give the user the ability to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Yes. `Background Agent` can run every 30 minutes and send location to a server

2.Yes. [`Microsoft.Maps.MapControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee690939.aspx) has all you need. For example draw lines with `MapPolyline` class:

```
 MapPolyline polyline = new MapPolyline();
 polyline.Locations = new LocationCollection();
 map.Children.Add(polyline);
```

3.You can do anything. Buttons can be Metro style with images also. But try to keep applications look in consistency with a system